# ReactJS class.contextType API gives undefined and empty values

Tags: reactjs

why is my function still empty object?? using `class.contextType` API

I am not wrapping the consumer i want to directly use it with `class.contextType` and access the provider values but its giving me false values

This is my provider

```
export const AuthServiceContext = React.createContext({
          user: null,
          isLoggedIn: false,
          _defaultLogin: () => {},
          _googleLogin: () => {}
})
export class AuthService extends React.Component{
   state = {
      user: null,
      isLoggedIn: false,
      _defaultLogin: this.useDefaultLogin,
      _googleLogin: this.useGoogleLogin
  }
}

useDefaultLogin(email, password){
   ....
}

....
render(){
    return (
    <AuthService.Provider value={this.state}>
         //Not really wrapping anything i want to directly get the context values
         </AuthService.Provider>
    )
}
```

This is my consumer, importing the context and using `class.contextType` api

```
import { AuthServiceContext } from './utils/AuthService'

class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    static myContext = AuthServiceContext;

    login = (e) => {
        const { _defaultLogin } = this.context;
        console.log(this.context) /* isAuthenticated: null,
                                     userData: null,
                                    _defaultLogin: () => {},
                                    _googleLogin: () => {},

                                    */
     _defaultLogin(email, password) // not a function
       ....
      }
}

Login.contextType = AuthServiceContext;;
```

`console.log(_defaultLogin)` // undefined

Comment: is login component wrapped by AuthService somewhere in the hierarchy

Comment: No.. is that necessary with contextType api? i thought i could access the context values without having to wrapped the consumer with provider with contextType?

Comment: With contextType API, you don't need to wrap with a consumer but a provider is still necessary somewhere in the hierarchy or else contextType will return you the default values passed on while creating the context

Comment: welp.. that's a shame i thought i could escape redundant component nesting.. thanks!!